# Is it possible to enforce shared-nothing multithreading at the level of the OS or programming language? (OSX, Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, multithreading, macos, concurrency

I'm trying to implement an actor model of concurrency in Objective-C, because I want to avoid the infamous problems of shared mutable state, locks, semaphores, etc. It can be done, but it takes *real* discipline to avoid accidentally using shared state.

One way to enforce the shared-nothing rule is to use separate processes instead of separate threads, but I think that's overkill and will have a nasty overhead. What I'd really like is something that achieves the same end, but in a more light-weight fashion. Is there anything that fits this description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question, sadly, is "No there's no OS facility that can enforce shared-nothing that's lighter weight than a process." In theory this would be an interesting direction for a static analysis tool (like clang) to take, but I'm not aware of any such tool today.

That said, have you had a close look at Grand Central Dispatch (aka libdispatch) and blocks?

My own experience has been that GCD and blocks dramatically simplify adhering to the discipline necessary for shared-nothing concurrency. You mention above that you're "already familiar with NSOperation, blocks, etc.", but I'd recommend really sitting down and exploring what you can do with them. Also, there are a lot of patterns possible with the dispatch APIs that aren't easily implemented on top of the NSBlockOperation / NSOperationQueue abstractions, so don't be afraid to delve into the underlying libdispatch APIs.

Answer (score 1):

[ActorKit](http://code.google.com/p/plactorkit/)

It's a little beta, but it works. Should give you a place to start worst case.

Answer (score 0):

Never fear the documentation! Take a look at [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) or a broader understanding via the [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091)

--Frank

Comment: I'm already familiar with NSOperation, blocks, etc. This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Then maybe a more succinct description (scenario) that provides better context would help.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach for you is message passing. Two actors or threads set of a communication channel between them. The semantics of this channel can be complex or simple. A simple semantics is that messages are atomically written and atomically consumed. This can be used to implement a shared nothing approach, and is the the method of choice for many programming models.

This the model that Google's GO language uses.